# Django rest Framework : Serializers and business logic

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Pages(models.Model):
     pagename = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
    )
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     pagenumber = models.IntegerField(default=1)


class Paras(models.Model):
     paraname = models.CharField(
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
    )
     id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
     paranumber = models.IntegerField(default=1)
     pagenumberID = models.ForeignKey(Pages, related_name='page')
```

Post API :/para
Post data :

```
{  
   pagename:Page1,
   pagenumber:1,
   paras:[  
      {  
         paraname:para1,
         paranumber:1
      },
      {  
         paraname:para2,
         paranumber:2
      },
      {  
         paraname:para3,
         paranumber:3
      }
   ]
}
```

The intent of the post API is to create multiple paras in one bulk call after creating the page.

I have two serialiazer :

- CreatePageSerializer(ModelSerializer) which expects the page name and page number
- CreateParaSerializer(ModelSerialzer) which expects the para name,the para number and the page number.

I am doubtful however how to process the complete request in one go. Keeping the business logic in the views , i.e calling the CreatePageSerializer first and then CreateParaSerializer, does not seem right.

I am thinking of creating another serializer : CreateBulkSerializer(BaseSerialzer) which would then call the CreatePageSerializer and CreateParaSerializer. However the questions are:

- How will I send the data to the CreateBulkSerializer (set as
  serializer context?)
- which would be be default function called? Would I need to override
  the **init** and then handle the logic there ?

Or is there any other approach that I am missing here?

Comment: Can you add the  models?

Comment: I have mentioned the fields. Ill reformat this a bit

Comment: That's ok. But, If you add the class definition of the model, that would be ***more easy to understand*** than current representation

Comment: I think you are trying to implement [Nested Writable Serializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)

Comment: @JPG : the concern is that : IMO the Modelserializers should be bound to the fields of the Model. ie. the validated_data should be the actual model fields. I do not want to polute the context of the ModelSerializers and hence I want to create a facilitating serializer.

Comment: The `validated_data`  may contain fields which are not part of the model, depends on how you'd defined the serializer

Comment: and I *feel* your ultimate requirement (creating bulk para after creating a page) can be done by overriding the `create()` method. Overriding the create method isn't a bad idea, because if you are create a seperate serializer for both the operation, you should write or override similar `create()` method

Comment: I will override the create function in the CreatePageSerializer  and CreateParaSerializer. These will handle the creation of one page and one para. But to pass the POST data which is in a combined format... isnt having a third serializer better? This serializer would then call the CreatePageSerializer  and CreateParaSerializer.

Comment: I could show an example with ***proper field*** if you add those two  model class defition

Comment: @JPG : sure....

Comment: @JPG: Done.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override the **create()** method as ,

```
class ParasSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Paras
        fields = ('paraname', 'paranumber')


class PagesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    paras = ParasSerializer(write_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Pages
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        paras = validated_data.pop('paras')
        page = Pages.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for para in paras:
            Paras.objects.create(**para, pagenumberID=page)
        return page
```

I would like to use **`viewset`** class for view,

```
from rest_framework import viewsets


class PagesAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Pages.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PagesSerializer
```

Use the below JSON for bulk creation,

```
{  
   "pagename":"Page1",
   "pagenumber":1,
  "paras":[  
      {  
         "paraname":"para1",
         "paranumber":1
      },
      {  
         "paraname":"para2",
         "paranumber":2
      },
      {  
         "paraname":"para3",
         "paranumber":3
      }
   ]
}
```

**Reference**
1. [write_only](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#write_only)
2. [DRF Nested relationship](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships)
3. [Writable Nested Serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers)